# Meteor livereload incredibly slow

Tags: meteor, angular, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

In my team we are running a meteor project and the livereload function is incredibly slow it is unnerving.

Is there anyway to make this faster?

Our project runs with Angular 2 on the front end in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There is a open issue in the repo for this with some helpful comments.

[Link to issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4284)

In my experience the biggest variable is Drive write speed (SSDs seem to really help) also CPU to a lesser degree. I have an MacBook pro which is v slow 15 sec vs my hackintosh which is more like 5 sec.

The other important aspect apparently is separating '/client' vs '/server' code effectively. Meteor will detect the location and only rebuild the relevant files vs a full rebuild.

This is a hot topic so I expect some improvement soon.

Here is another good article on medium [link](https://medium.com/@lucashansen/faster-meteor-reloads-62cca5b56460#.65oxznfzd)